# Usage of plot results

Tags: plotting, export

Please consider the following examples for a `ListLinePlot` and `ListPlot`

```
data=Prime[Range[25]];
lstlinePlot=ListLinePlot[data];
lstPlot=ListPlot[Tooltip@data];
```

**Displaying plot-values**

As I would like to give the user the chance to retrieve plot-values directly from the plot, I thought to overlay `lstlinePlot` with `lstPlot`, whereas for the latter the plot-values are displayed via `Tooltip`:

```
res=Show[{lstlinePlot,lstPlot}]
```

To evaluate two plots based on the same data seems to me rather time consuming. I wonder whether there is a more efficient way to make the plot-values available as via `Tooltip` (I thought of enabling a "display modus" within `Mesh` but this does not seem to exist.)

**Retrieving plot-data directly from plot**

It would be nice to be able to click on the line of `lstlinePlot`, press the copy shortcut (e.g. cmd+c) and paste the data into another notebook or into a txt-file (as plain text maybe). I know how to retrieve data from a plot (e.g. `lstlinePlot[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1, All, 2]]`) but I would like to make data available via copy-paste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first question, J.M. provided this code which works nicely:

```
ListPlot[Tooltip /@ Prime[Range[25]], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to use `ListLinePlot` with `PlotMarkers`, which allows the points to have the same colour as the lines when there are multiple lines:

```
plot = ListLinePlot[Tooltip /@ {Prime[Range[25]], Range[25]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Regarding your second point: I don't know how to override the standard copy-paste in the front end, but here is a code snippet which will make a "Copy Data" button appear when you hover over a line in the plot and press the Control button on the keyboard:

```
Normal[plot] /. Line[data__] :> Dynamic[
   If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"] && CurrentValue["ControlKey"],
    {Line[data],
     Inset[Button["Copy Data", CopyToClipboard[data]],
      MousePosition["Graphics"]]}, Line[data]]]
```

[image]

I added the `"ControlKey"` trigger to prevent flickering between the `Tooltip` and `Button` displays. The `Normal` is needed to convert `GraphicsComplex` expressions to standard graphics primitives, so that the copied data is the actual coordinates rather than the `GraphicsComplex` indices.

Comment: Maybe it would be best if you copy my answer into yours, and then I will delete my answer, so that your answer is the complete one...

Comment: @SimonWoods The behaviour of the button is a bit strange. It does not change its colour immediately when I touch another line. (Maybe my Mac is reacting to slow?)

Comment: @John, see my edit - I think this is much improved now.

Comment: @J.M., done, thanks. This should probably have been two separate questions really.

Comment: @SimonWoods Two more things I did not mentioned before: (1) It would be nice to have the button to appear above the line and (2) if the button touches one of the `PlotMarkers` `Clipboard` should only copy the corresponding data-point.

Comment: @John, the button needs to be at the mouse position, or it will disappear when you move the mouse off the line to get to the button. Change `Line` to `Point` in the code to get a button that works on the individual data points.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was inspired by Alexei Boulbitch's idea of  using a locator, but implements it in what I think is a more user friendly way. The locator and its visible marker are constrained to the data points plotted. The user need only click near the point that he/she wants copied to the clipboard and the locator will jump to that point. The argument determining whether or not the plot is joined had been made optional with `True` as the default.

```
listPlotWithCopy[data_List, joined : (True | False) : True] :=
   DynamicModule[{pt = {1, data[[1]]}},
      Column[{Framed@
         LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
            ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Medium, Joined -> joined,
               Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large],
                  Dynamic@Point[With[{n = Round@pt[[1]]},
                     pt = {n, data[[n]]}]]}],
            Appearance -> None],
         Button["Copy Red Point to Clipboard", CopyToClipboard[pt],
            ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}]},
         Right]]
```

Here is how the output looks with the plot joined:

```
data = Range[25] + RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 25];
listPlotWithCopy[data]
```

[image: Joined plot]

And here it is with joining turned off:

```
listPlotWithCopy[data, False]
```

[image: Unjoined plot]

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you had in mind, but has the same function. Try this:

```
    pickUpValue[lst_List, sz_Integer, join_] := 
 DynamicModule[{toClipboard, 
   pt = {IntegerPart[Length[lst]/2], 
     lst[[IntegerPart[Length[lst]/2]]]}},

  Column[{
            Show[{
             ListPlot[lst, ImageSize -> sz, Joined -> join],
                    Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt]]]          
                }],

      Button["Copy it", toClipboard = pt; CopyToClipboard[toClipboard]]

       }]]
```

In it variables the parameter join takes the values True and False. For example, assume this is the list:

```
lst = Range[25] + RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 25];
```

Let us evaluate it:

```
pickUpValue[lst, 400, True]
```

This enables one to pick up the value using the locator, and to copy it into the clipboard by pressing the button
[image: The screen shot]